# how to create multi language mvc site with database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nopcommerce-3.80

I want to create multi language mvc site with database which is each language has a key and language Id and value but i do not know how should i call this value in landing page.
I read `Nopcommerce` multi language Implementation but did not understand so much.
Is there any references to guide solutions about this method of multi language implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Nop can do that.

http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/Localization

admin-demo.nopcommerce.com

The backend of nop does seem complicated, but once you get a hang of it, its actually pretty simple.

http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/User+guide